Перемещение рандомных файлов с помощью ffmpeg
Например:
На диске D есть 2 папки before и after. В папке before может лежать большое количество файлов в формате mp4. Можно ли и как с помощью ffmpeg перенести 6 рандомных файлов с папки before в папку after?
Прошу помощи в реализации.

Get-Random -InputObject (Get-ChildItem -Path $before) -Count 6 |ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $after -Force }
